# Data model is not getting deserialised in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

Here is my model class

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public Product {set;set;} // Product is one more class
}
```

I am using below javascript code to get partial view but '**model**' is not getting deserialised in controller...What I am missing?

Storing data in a HTML attribute as shown below

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObject = serializer.Serialize(obj)

<span data-singleproduct="@jsonObject" id="@mprodid" class="ShowProductModal">Find out more..</span>
```

Used jQuery to call partial page and popup

```
$('.ShowProductModal').on('click', function () {
    var model = $(this).data('singleproduct');
    //I can see data of variable model here in developer tool

    $("#ProductModal").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
        width: 1000,
        resizable: false,
        title: '',
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            $(this).load('ShowProductModal', model );

        },
        buttons: {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is my controller code

```
public PartialViewResult ShowProductModal(ProductModel product)
{
    return PartialView("ProductModal", product);
}
```

product always comes as null!!!

If I change **ProductModel** to **Product** , then it will work... ! CAN SOMEONE HELP ME?

```
public PartialViewResult ShowProductModal(Product product)
{
    return PartialView("ProductModal", product);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(model);` to see what is in your model you are passing to your controller?

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
$(this).load('ShowProductModal', { product: model });
```

And declare your method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ShowProductModal([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    var product = data["product"].ToObject<ProductModel>();
    return PartialView("_SC5ProductModal", product);
}
```

Comment: no luck, I htink 'model' is not able to fit in to 'ProductModel'.  Is my serialization method is wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't `$(this).load` uses a `HttpGet`?

Comment: What about now?

I don't know your models. But what you CAN try is instead of receiving `ProductModel product` try receiving `JObject data` and debug into it. If you wanna try it with `JObject` make sure to call your `.load()` with `{ product: model }` then!

Comment: `$(this).load` uses `HttpGet` per default, yes. But if body as object is provided it will use `HttpPost`.

Comment: Its now not hitting the controller, In console i see it is passing now object type!

Comment: Error in console -  http://localhost:51988/products/ShowProductModal?%22ProjectName.Models.ProductModel%22 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I edited my answer. This has to work now. You can set a breakpoint and look into data to see what exactly has given to the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122675/discussion-between-codetoshare-and-ferhat-sayan).